# Why I am Not able to create and add data to the sqlite file at the same time?

Tags: ios, sqlite

In My current ios application I have to add tables and insert data to the added table for new version.
By taking Upgrade into consideration I did it through the code itself Like below

```
-(void)lessThan100TableQuery
{
    NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE 'Table_Name' ('item_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , 'item_section' INTEGER, 'item_no' INTEGER, 'bullet_no' VARCHAR, 'heading' INTEGER, 'hide_controls' INTEGER, 'description' VARCHAR);INSERT INTO 'Table_Name' VALUES(1,1,0,'',1,1,'Condition/adequacy of distributor''s/supply intake equipment');"
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
                return NO;
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
}
```

(like above I add 100 rows I skipped them here)

But by calling the above method only the table get added without the values

I cross checked it by running the above query in sqlitemanager and working fine without any issue. It is not working in code.

Help me out folks

Comment: Check if database connectivity is proper. I mean if its open when required.

Comment: @Kiran I check it in the before method and in addition if connection is not set then table iteself won't get created. how come only table created

Comment: Did you try to make separate queries, i.e. 1. Create table; 2. Insert values? I think, it's not possible to make nested queries like you are doing. Also, how about using some sqlite wrapper libs like FMDB?

Comment: @FahriAzimov yes That helped me.

Comment: @FahriAzimov can you point me some other link detailing the reason

Comment: You can find FMDB here - https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb. Reason to use it, well, it's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sqlite3_prepare_v2() documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) says:

> These routines only compile the first statement in zSql

To execute multiple statements, you have to use a loop, and use `pzTail` to skip over the previously-executed statement.